# Match a pattern that does not contain a specific subpattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I want to find the records that match a given text pattern but where a section of the pattern is different from a specific value. For example, a record of the `Page` table could have a `PageId` field and a `Description` text field that look like:

```
PageId: 3718
Description: Page 3718 contains... Page 3718 contains...
```

I know that I can build a LIKE condition to match the `PageId`:

```
Description LIKE '%Page ' + CAST(P.PageId as varchar(8)) + ' contains%'
```

But what I want is the opposite. I want to find the records where at least one page ID in the `Description` field does not match the actual `PageId` value. That would enable me to detect records like the following:

```
PageId: 3718
Description: Page 4092 contains... Page 3718 contains...
```

I know how I would do it using a regular expression in code but how can I do it in SQL?

Comment: Can you show us some more sample table data, and also _specify_ the expected result, i.e. provide a complete [mcve]. Also note that tables have _rows_ and _columns_, not records or fields.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: Usually you have to do it in two steps. `WHERE column LIKE '%page%contains...%' and column NOT LIKE '%page%3718%contains...%'` of course this is not bulletproof, but that's tsql for you

Comment: @siggemannen - Thanks for your suggestion. I modified my question a little bit to better illustrate my problem. The "bad" records that I try to find may contain the pattern with the "correct" `PageId` value, but they are bad if at least one of the page ID is wrong.

Comment: Ok, then it's harder. is `pageid` always 4 chars? or can it be anything or is there any kind of pattern to it

Comment: @siggemannen - `PageId` itself is an integer (auto-increment) but it appears as text in the `Description` field.

Comment: ok, so it doesn't have any fixed length?

Comment: @siggemannen - Exact. In the question, I cast it to a `varchar(8)` in my LIKE condition attempt, just in case it goes up to 8 digits in a distant future.

Comment: Are you on sql server 2022?

Comment: SQL Server 2019.

Comment: SQL, the language, is bad at text processing and `LIKE` is very limited. What you ask requires parsing the content, so at the very least you need regular expressions. T-SQL doesn't support regular expressions.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Yes, it would be easy with regular expressions. I am afraid I may have to write application code for this.

Comment: Ok, then perhaps: `WHERE REPLACE(column, 'Page 3718 contains', '') LIKE '%page%contains...%'` :)

Comment: @siggemannen - Hmmm, that is a very good idea! I will try it and let you know (so that you could write an answer that I will accept). Thanks!

Comment: @siggemannen - Your suggestion works very well! I only had to replace `'Page 3718 contains'` with `'Page ' + CAST(PageId as varchar(8)) + ' contains'`. Can you post an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
REPLACE(x, 'Page ' + CAST(PageId as varchar(8)) + ' contains', '') LIKE '%Page%contains%'
```

to try to match the odd strings.

Note that this will match too much on string containing word 'contains' outside of the 'page contains' pattern.

Comment: Clever thinking batman

Answer (score 1):

With an example...

```
CREATE TABLE SQL_Server_Query
(PageId INT PRIMARY KEY,
 "Description" VARCHAR(max));

INSERT INTO SQL_Server_Query VALUES
(3718, 'Page 3718 contains... Page 3718 contains...: Page 3718 contains... Page 3718 contains...'),
(3719, 'Page 4092 contains... Page 3719 contains...');
```

The query can be:

```
SELECT PageId
FROM   SQL_Server_Query 
       CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE("Description", 'Page ', CHAR(0)), CHAR(0))
WHERE  value NOT LIKE CAST(PageId AS VARCHAR(32)) + '%'
  AND  value <> ''
```

Comment: My SQL Server 2019 does not recognize `STRING_SPLIT`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan - `STRING_SPLIT` is SQL Server 2016+. Are you sure you are on 2019? This query has no specific logic for "contains" though so will also match "Page NNNN" not followed by the string " contains"

Comment: @MartinSmith - I get `Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'.` With `SELECT @@Version`, I get `Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU22-GDR) (KB5029378) - 15.0.4326.1 (X64)`. Could it be the position of `STRING_SPLIT` in the query that is incorrect?

Comment: Probably the compatibility level of the database. What is that set to?

Comment: The use of `CHAR(0)` here breaks things anyway on my collation (`Latin1_General_CI_AS`)

Comment: @MartinSmith - Good point about the compatibility level. My database is very old and has 2008 compatibility.

Comment: This works for me with the Latin1_General_CI_AS collation in SQL Server 20022. But instead of CHAR(0) you can use any not printable char that you are sure it is not in the string...

Comment: @SQLpro - Sorry for not being able to test it.

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't changed the compatibility level, @ConnorsFan ?

Comment: @ThomA - I just learned today that there was such a thing and I don't know if changing it can have any side effect. But I will consider it.

Comment: @ConnorsFan it is because SQL Server is the only RDBMS able to works in different compatibility modes since 2008 version.... Other RDBMS does'nt do this !